# Using httpget when no data is changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I remember reading & have been told you should only use `[httppost]` on controller actions that may change data (I can't find these sources though - and am unable to find anything on Google).

And if you are - say, just doing a lookup of data you should use `[httpget]`.

I have 2 controller actions - used only for looking up data, never for changing it.

I have tried using two `[httpget]s` this in an ASP.NET MVC 5 controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(Guid Id)
{
    // Id is used to populate the form
}

// I would previously have placed [httppost] here
public ActionResult MyAction(MyObject myobj)
{
    // myobj is posted back from the form - but no data is changed in the database, it's just a lookup
}
```

However, I get this error:

> The current request for action 'MyAction' on controller type
>   'MyController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:

The compiler is having a problem with ambiguous method names - so what is best practice for doing this?

Do we have to use a form specifying an explicitly different action? (this seems inelegant and messy - it makes `[httppost]` look simpler, more elegant and more terse if that is the case).

Is it indeed the case that we should use `[httpget]` in situations where no data is being persisted?

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two methods with the same name in your controller. And action resolver can not decide which one to use.

Easiest way is to follow naming convention, in this case you won't have to put attributes:

```
public ActionResult GetMyAction(Guid Id)
{
    // Id is used to populate the form
}

// I would previously have placed [httppost] here
public ActionResult PostMyAction(MyObject myobj)
{
    // myobj is posted back from the form - but no data is changed in the database, it's just a lookup
}
```

However if you want to stay with your names, you will have to put appropriate attributes:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetMyAction(Guid Id)
{
    // Id is used to populate the form
}

// I would previously have placed [httppost] here
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostMyAction(MyObject myobj)
{
    // myobj is posted back from the form - but no data is changed in the database, it's just a lookup
}
```

Comment: Hi - I think you are missing my point. I thought you weren't supposed to post a form if no data was changed - that you were supposed to get the form instead & only post where data was changed?!

Comment: nope, if you post the whole object is posted back, it is your job to check if any part of the object is changed

Comment: @niico `only post where data was changed` at this moment server does not know if something changed or not. What you can do, is check it on client(javascript) and prevent POST, but this is completely different topic

Comment: Sorry again I wasn't clear. Data *will never be changed* for these actions - it is *only ever for lookup*

Comment: How are you planning on passing `MyObject` in a `GET` request?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the rationale for get vs post. The important thing is not that post requests always change the state, the important thing is get requests never change state. One great example was a content management system that regularly experienced their content inexplicably disappearing before figuring out that a web crawler was indexing an admin page and following their deletion hyperlinks, all using http get, or prefetching browsers randomly adding or removing shopping cart items.

That said, I'd probably still make both of these gets using different actions, because the get verb better describes the service action, but maybe you have good reasons not to do that.

Comment: Yes, I agree on get not updating. So you would just use a longer form definition specifying a different action name then, even though it is more verbose?